# SQL: Script changes from WEEK to MONTH

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

Wondering if all you lovely people can help. I need a script which is going to be used by my planning team. The team need to see the value per month of inbound purchase orders. The report is to only show placed purchase orders, not include historic in the value calculation. Value will be unit price. I need it grouped by supplier number and supplier name. The calculation for each month should be StockOnOrder * unitPrice.

I have these columns from two tables which should have all the data in them:

- (Table: PurchaseOrder) Column: supplierNumber **(NVARCHAR(20),null)** - This is the supplier number
- (Table: PurchaseOrder) Column: supplierName **(NVARCHAR(60),null)** - Name of supplier
- (Table: PurchaseOrder) Column: StockOnOrderByDate **(NVARCHAR(10),null)** - Populated like '**20220223 - YYYYMMDD**'
- (Table: PurchaseOrder) Column: StockOnOrder **(INT,null)** - Total on order
- (Table: Item) Column: UnitPrice **(NUMERIC(15,4),null)** - Cost of one unit

Is there a way with the information I've provided someone could create something for me?

Essentially what I'm looking for is something like this...

| supplierNumber | SupplierName | January | February | March | more month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Test Supplier | £XXX.XX | £XXX.XX | £XXX.XX | £XXX.XX | £XXXXXX.XX |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I've not tried anything yet, was just reaching out before I tried myself.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Got this but not sure how to get it in monthly format.

SELECT 
  supplierNumber,
  supplierName,
  [Total] = SUM(PurchaseOrder.StockOnOrder * Item.unitPrice)
 FROM Item
 JOIN PurchaseOrder
  ON Item.ItemCode = PurchaseOrder.ItemCode
 GROUP BY 
   supplierNumber,
   supplierName

Comment: "I've not tried anything yet, was just reaching out before I tried myself." -> should be vice versa because helping people with a specific question is the better option compared to doing the whole work and writing the code for them.

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_ (for each month.)

Comment: @jarlh Sorry I've not used CASE expression before. How would this look in case query?

Comment: Something like `sum(case when month(datecol) = 1 then amount else 0 end)`

Comment: @jarlh Been playing around with that and I don't think I understand it. Where you have '(datecol) = 1' What is this actually saying? It it just looking for a value of 1 within the date column? Also, where you have 'then amount' Amount is another column, I'm assuming I put unitPrice here?

Comment: unitPrice sounds correct. (I didn't bother checking out actual column names.)

Comment: Doesn't `month(datecol)` return 1 for January dates? (I've never used SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to achieve your ask.
The following code uses the WideWorldImportersDW sample database to provide data in place of your own table data. The dates are between 2013 & 2016 and provide an order  count of 8367 rows.

The final output is 87 rows

```
SELECT 
    p.[Supplier Key] supplierNumber,
    s.[Supplier] AS supplierName,
    MONTH([Date Key]) OrderMonth, 
    YEAR([Date Key]) OrderYear,
    SUM([Ordered Quantity] * i.[Unit Price])  TotalPrice
FROM [Fact].[Purchase] p
JOIN [Dimension].[Stock Item] i ON p.[Stock Item Key] = i.[Stock Item Key]
JOIN [Dimension].[Supplier] s ON p.[Supplier Key] = s.[Supplier Key]
GROUP BY
    p.[Supplier Key] ,
    s.[Supplier],
    MONTH([Date Key]), 
    YEAR([Date Key])
```

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for getting back to you so late! This looks great but struggling to figure out what column names to change to make it work for my scenario. Could you help?

Comment: Is this correct?
SELECT
 ArticlePurchaseOrder.supplierNumber,
 ArticlePurchaseOrder.supplierName,
 MONTH(StockOnOrderByDate) OrderMonth,
 YEAR(ArticlePurchaseOrder.StockOnOrderByDate) OrderYear,
 SUM(ArticlePurchaseOrder.StockOnOrder * unitPrice) TotalPrice
FROM ArticlePurchaseOrder
JOIN Article on ArticlePurchaseOrder.ArticleCode = Article.articleCode
GROUP BY
 ArticlePurchaseOrder.supplierNumber,
 ArticlePurchaseOrder.supplierName,
 MONTH(ArticlePurchaseOrder.StockOnOrderByDate),
 YEAR(ArticlePurchaseOrder.StockOnOrderByDate)

Comment: I want it to separate the OrderMonth into separate columns for each month.